# How to set connection timeout to sshtunnel

Tags: python, ssh-tunnel

I use SSHTunnelForwarder from sshtunnel module on python.

Given the next code:

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (sshServer, sshPort),
    ssh_username=sshUsername,
    ssh_password=sshPassword,
    remote_bind_address=(imapServer, imapPort),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', localPort)
)

print('STARTING')

server.start()

print(server.is_active)
```

Sometimes it take really long time, maybe few minutes, and then I get error:

```
2019-04-22 22:25:54,365| ERROR   | Could not connect to gateway ip..... : 110
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PYTHON_TUNNEL.py", line 24, in <module>
    server.start()
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1295, in start
    reason='Could not establish session to SSH gateway')
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1101, in _raise
    raise exception(reason)
sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway
```

Ubuntu 18.04, python 2.7

Is it possible to set timeout for tunnel establishment ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an [`SSH_TIMEOUT`](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L50) constant with a default of `None` in `sshtunnel.py` that is set on the [socket used to create the transport](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L1117-L1119) before calling `connect` on it.

Unfortunately, I can't test this myself, but you could try patching that constant before starting the tunnel forwarder:

```
import sshtunnel

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0

server = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder([...])    
server.start()
```

There's also a [`TUNNEL_TIMEOUT`](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L44) constant, but that seems to be used for [checks if the tunnel is already established](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L1253-L1260) and for the call to [`open_channel`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.open_channel) on the [underlying Paramiko Transport instance](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L336-L340). It does not seem to play a role during the creation of the tunnel.
Plus, `TUNNEL_TIMEOUT` is set to one second by default, and with you experiencing minute-long delays on `server.start()` before the `BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError` is raised, it seems unlikely that this constant is relevant for a solution to your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much!